# Connection between inequalities among ratios

Tags: inequality

Suppose we have 6 variables $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\Bbb Z^+$ and each being distinct, such that $\dfrac{a}{b}\lt\dfrac{c}{d}\lt\dfrac{e}{f}$. It is further said that $af-be=-1$. Can someone help me understand how the values of c and d are influenced by these conditions?
I have seen that $\frac{e}{f}-\frac{a}{b}=\frac{1}{bf}$, so the difference of $\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}$ or $\frac{e}{f}-\frac{c}{d}$ must be less than $\frac{1}{bf}$ but something less than one part of a number must have a larger denominator. So, is there a connection?

Comment: Take a geometric interpretation : represent vectors $U:=(b,a),V:=(d,c),W=(f,c)$. Hou have 1) a double inequation between the vectors' "slopes" 2) a constraint on the determinant that I write $be-af=1$ which means geometrically that the area of the parallelogram generated by U and W is equal to 1.

Comment: You may want to check the Stern–Brocot tree at wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree#Additional_properties).  Clearly the middle rational is below the level of the other two and lower down, but there still remains an infinite amount of choices for $c/d$.